# popup hidden behind highlight of selected text

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cordova, mobile

I'm implementing a functionality of text highlighting in mobile.
When the user long-touches a text, I show him a popup where he can choose to highlight the selected text.

My problem is that the shadow that covers the selected text appears above my popup.

You can see it in the picture below.

How can I make the popup comes above the text ?

I've already tried the z-index solution and it does not work.
More precisely, I've put a really high z-index on the popup container (200000000020) and it didn't changed anything.

Also, I don't have this issue on the desktop version of my application, only on my mobile version which I've build using Cordova.

Thanks a lot for your help.

[image]

Comment: What code are you using to generate the popup? It could be that the iOS selection also selects the popup because of its position in the DOM.

Comment: This look more like a browser default. I wouldn't say there is much that you can do about it. As the user is interacting with the text not the popup. In all honesty the popup should not be there just now if the user is selecting text. and if the user click on the link to get the popup then the text selection should disappear.

Comment: I'm using a customize version of annotatorJS. The code for selection is something like this :  var selection = Util.getGlobal().getSelection(); var range = document.createRange(); range.selectNodeContents(target); selection.removeAllRanges(); selection.addRange(normedRange.toRange());

Comment: @Andrew, the popup appears after the selection has ended (at touchEnd). When the user clicks on the popup, on annotate for example, the text selection disappears

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar issue here. Also tried adding a really high 9999999999 z index to my dropdown but no luck. It happens when you select some text then open the dropdown, the selected text still appears over the dropdown and doesn't let you interact with the dropdown contents

[image of selected text appearing over dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5hk8.png)

Comment: When you have similar problems, You should upvote questions.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29878096)